# Summation function in a range in Python

Tags: python, numpy, sum

I'm new on Python and I have to do an exercise. I have to write a function using summation in a range from 1 to N. N values are [1, 2, 5, 100, 700].  I have to calculate the value od F for each value of N. The function is

```
F(N) = 4/N * ∑ * 1/1+((i-1/2)/N)**2
```

I read something about sum in numpy but I'm in trouble because my ∑ is within the range i from 1 to N.

```
import numpy as np 
N = [1, 2, 5, 100, 700]
```

and I was thinking about using `for i in range (N).`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know why you were down voted, but perhaps because people want you to show what you've done for homework questions. Doing so is necessary for homework questions.

Comment: You probably don't need numpy for this -- Python has a builtin `sum` function.  Try running, for example, `sum(i * 2 for i in range(1, 5))`.  Once you understand how that works (`0*2 + 1*2 + 2*2 + 3*2 + 4*2 == 20`), just replace `i * 2` with the Python expression that corresponds to whatever is on the right hand side of your sigma.

Comment: Try analyzing the formula mathematically, for example,  `∑ (i + 1/2)**2 = ∑(i**2) + ∑i + ∑1/4` and you can use formulas for the sum of squares and arithmetic progression to compute the result without any loops at all.

Comment: `1/1+((i-1/2)/N)**2` should work with `i=np.arange(1,N+1)`.